# How vulnerable is my code to SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, security

Ok I don't want this to be a hacking advice question, so please don't down-vote for that.  I work in a web shop and I've found some of our old PHP pages are vulnerable to SQL injection in the username and want to know how bad.

We use a PHP string to embed the user input from the POST on the login form.

```
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$pass  = md5($_POST['pass']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pass' AND userlevel='user'";
...
```

then I run the query.

Now, I'm no SQL expert, I just use what I can  piece together on phpMyAdmin.  But I was able to log in without a username by instead using:

```
' OR 1 '
```

I know to escape the user input, I use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

My question is, how vulnerable is this code, and could someone log into this page and not need the password?  I would think maybe they wouldn't need the username, but could only brute force the password.  But I'm no SQL guru and am wondering if some tricks could be used against us.

We use MySQL.

And please I don't need any lectures on input validation, I know how bad this is.  We should be doing lots of things, like timeouts and lockouts on our page so it can't be brute-forced.

Comment: What is the login logic? if mysql_num_rows(query) == 1 it is ok? You must fetch password(depending on the username) and then to check passwords for equality...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm voting to close. You answered your own question right in your post.

Comment: um, no I didn't.  I'm asking how severely vulnerable this is and if they can login without the password.  It's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Could someone log into this page and not need the password": Yes, trivially.  Try the username `yourfavoriteadmin' OR 1; --`.

[May as well link this, since certainly somebody will...](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  You sure that works with my single quotes? Can you elaborate and explain?  And yes, I know that comic. :)

Comment: If it doesn't work, that's good news, but I can't say I know why not. :)  `--` is like `//` in C++, designates the rest of the line as a comment.

Comment: Hmm, is there a mysql feature that disables comments?

Comment: It also depends on your version of PHP - PHP will have its various "magic" cleaning functions on or off depending on the whim of the PHP team that day of the week. So some vulnerablities might not work so long as you are running on exactly the right version of PHP (unless someone then uses the encoding vulnerabilities in PHPs magic functions to bypass them).

Answer (score 9):

It’s very vulnerable. If you know about all the nifty stuff like `mysql_real_escape_string` why do you waste your time and ask this question? You should be all over that code, fixing it. You know, like, **NOW**.

Comment: it's fixed, I was just wondering how long the back door is open, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

The code as written isn't technically vulnerable at all. Your SQL query contains variable $username but you never initialize it or set it to anything. That's a bug and you'll never get a valid result from MySQL.

Once you fix that bug, however, you should be escaping your variables with mysql_real_escape_string().

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: +1 for pointing out the typo. Now, just hope that register_globals is off, as that could allow people to "initialize" $username.

Comment: fixed.  good catch.  I didn't copy and paste my actual code for obvious reasons. ;)

Comment: I thought about register_globals, but since it's off by default and it's a pretty basic question, my guess is that the user was unlikely to have enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

try where $_POST['username'] is:

```
no one'; delete from users --
```

Comment: multiple statements typically have no effect with php's mysql interface

Comment: Cute, but you forgot the `FROM`.

Comment: the mysqli interface will perform multiple queries if you use mysqli::multi_query, but then you're just asking for trouble :)

Comment: @chaos, added the "from", it is optional where I work most of the time (SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Always clean up your data before using in any SQL query, if you're working with PHP >= 5.2, you have [the Filter functions](http://www.php.net/filter).

Simple question : why don't change the order WHERE pass = 'blabl' AND username = 'bla' ?
Have you an index on this fields ?

Another question: what is the point with this line

```
$uname = $_POST['username'];
```

adding a variable, just for quoting/double-quoting effect in concatenation ? Without filtering nor escaping data ?